# Excel VBA: "Too many different cell formats" - Is there a way to remove or clear these formats in a Macro?

Tags: vba, excel, cell-formatting

So, I made a fun and simple macro that randomly selects R, G, and B values until it uses every possible combination (skipping repeats), and setting the color values of a 10x10 square with each new color.

The only problem is that I have run into the limit for the number of cell formats. [Microsoft says that the limit should be around 64000](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/213904), but I found it to be exactly 65429 on a blank workbook in Excel 2013.

I've included a clear format code, but it seems to have no effect:

```
Cells(X, Y).ClearFormats
```

Microsoft lists some resolutions, but 3 out of the 4 of them are essentially "Don't make too many formats", and the 4th format is to use a third party application.

Is there really nothing that can be done in VBA?

---

- A1:J10 will print a new color
- K1 will print the percentage to completion
- L1 will print the number of colors used
- M1 will print the number of times a color combination is repeated

  ```
  Dim CA(255, 255, 255) As Integer
  Dim CC As Long
  Dim RC As Long
  Dim R As Integer
  Dim G As Integer
  Dim B As Integer
  Dim X As Integer
  Dim Y As Integer

  CC = 0
  RC = 0

  X = 1
  Y = 1

  Do While ColorCount < 16777216
      R = ((Rnd * 256) - 0.5)
      G = ((Rnd * 256) - 0.5)
      B = ((Rnd * 256) - 0.5)

      If CA(R, G, B) <> 1 Then
          CA(R, G, B) = 1

          'Step down to the next row
          'If at the 10th row, jump back to the first and move to the next column
          If X < 10 Then
              X = X + 1
          Else
              X = 1
              If Y < 10 Then
                  Y = Y + 1
              Else
                  Y = 1
              End If
          End If

          Cells(X, Y).ClearFormats 'doesn't do what I hope :(
          Cells(X, Y).Interior.Color = RGB(R, G, B)
          CC = CC + 1
          Cells(1, 11).Value = (CC / 16777216) * 100
          Cells(1, 12).Value = CC
      Else
          RC = RC + 1
          Cells(1, 13).Value = RC
      End If

  Loop
  ```

Comment: I actually wouldn't say what's the solution to this issue. But where are you updating `ColorCount`?

Comment: Color Array ("CA") holds 256x256x256 entries. If CA(R, G, B) is not set to 1, then set it to 1 (to consider it used). Then, I set the background color of the cell a little bit lower:

    Cells(X, Y).Interior.Color = RGB(R, G, B)

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to resolve this issue, but the cleanest and easiest method is to remove all extra styles (I have seen workbooks with 9000+ styles )

With the following simple VBA code you can remove all non-builtin styles and in the vast majority of cases this fixes the error.

```
Sub removeStyles() 
Dim li as long 
On Error Resume Next 

With ActiveWorkbook 
For li = .Styles.Count To 1 Step -1 
If Not .Styles(li).BuiltIn Then 
.Styles(li).Delete 
End If 
Next 
End With 
End Sub
```